# Geolocation button in Kotlin application is unavailable

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to create a maps application that can take your location and same time save your markers.

But I'm getting trouble try to adding a `FloatingButton` same time.

This is my `content_main.XML` with [LoactionButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkXMa.jpg)
and the .XML of previous is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="13"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/app_name"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've been replace the `LinearLayout` element with `RelativeLayout` because trying to a `FloatingButton` in `content_main.xml` I obtain the [next](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uq8c7.jpg)
. The .xml image previous is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="13"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFF"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:fabSize="normal">
    </com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>

</LinearLayout>
```

So searching many examples in google I saw some people use the `RelativeLayout` to put `FloatingButton` in main content. I decided to change to put `RelativeLayout`, but `LocationButton` is unavailable like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kC8ro.jpg) the previous .xml is the next, and is the actual:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="13"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFF"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:fabSize="normal">
    </com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I searching many examples and I modified my `content_main.xml` but I have no solutions to put the location button with FloatingButton.

how can add a `FloatingButton` with my actual `LocationButton`?

**EDIT:** this is my `ButtonLocation`

```
 override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap //Princiapal Map Variable
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this) //Location Marker
        mMap.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true //Zoom in maps enabled
        mMap.uiSettings.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = true

        setUpMap() //Function to detect actual location
    }
```

**EDIT IMAGE:**

This is my actual [Layout mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8F7S.jpg) with [This .xml](https://pastebin.com/T2WqFfJW). But now I have the issue with the `Toolbar Widget`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have something there.
The red floating button is on top of the map, which is what you want.
To see Google's location button (normally at top-right corner), you need to issue:

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
```

Edit: For kotlin, use the following snippet:

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
  mMap = googleMap

  this.setUpMap()
}

companion object {
  private const val LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1
}

private fun setUpMap() {

  if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
      android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
      arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
    return
  }

  mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int,
                                        permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
  when (requestCode) {
    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE -> {
      // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
      if ((grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
        // permission was granted, yay! Do the task you need to do.
        setUpMap()
      } else {
        // permission denied, boo!
      }
      return
    }
    else -> {
      // Ignore all other requests.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have answered your comment. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, lurker0152, I've modified my .kt code with your examples, but is not working. The location button stills be unavailalbe.

Comment: Did your app requested Location permissions? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/location

Comment: Yes. It has request user application. The fact is about .xml configurations. This is my actual layers xml code: . https://pastebin.com/T2WqFfJW in a moment I will update the result in image

Comment: Please see the edited answer. Google's location button (top-right) should appear and blue-dot showing current user's location.